# Algorithm for finding a (x,y) within and on perimeter of a square and cross

Tags: algorithm, shapes, point

I have a school assignment, which requires me to find out whether a certain point (x,y) is inside a shape which for example lets say a square.

```
Class Square
private:
    int coordX[4];
    int coordY[4];
```

A cross has 12 points however,

```
Class Cross
private:
    int coordX[12];
    int coordY[12];
```

These are the attributes for the square. So lets say the square coordinates are (1,1) (1,4) (4,1) (4,4), how should I go about finding out whether the point (2,2) is inside the square?

```
bool isPointInShape (int, int)
```

The function is meant to take in two integers which is the point you want to check for, and it will return true or false.

```
bool isPointOnShape (int, int);
```

Same for the function which checks whether the point is on the perimeter of the shape.

Can someone help as to what is the algorithm to figure out how to calculate these 2 functions?

Comment: Why does a square have 8 points associated with it, and what is the meaning of a cross?

Comment: 4 points of x and 4 points of y, so if u actually consider x and y tgt its 4 points of x,y. A cross is like a medical centre sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Square {
private:
    int coordX[4];
    int coordY[4];
    int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

public:
    Square();
    bool is_point_on_shape (int, int);
};

Square::Square(int coordXIn[], int coordYIn[])
{
    coordX = coordXIn;
    coordY = coordYIn;

    // determine extreme x and y values, which define the box
    xMin = coordX[0];
    xMax = coordX[0];
    yMin = coordY[0];
    yMax = coordY[0];

    for (int i=1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (coordX[i] < xMin)
        {
            xMin = coordX[i];
        }

        if (coordX[i] > xMax)
        {
            xMax = coordX[i];
        }
        if (coordY[i] < YMin)
        {
            yMin = coordY[i];
        }

        if (coordY[i] > yMax)
        {
            yMax = coordY[i];
        }
    }
}

// since we have the range of x and y values, checking to see if a point be
// inside the square just means checking that this point lies within the range
bool Square::is_point_on_shape (int x, int y)
{
    if (xMin + x > xMax) return false;
    if (yMin + y > yMax) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but for a cross how do you think it should be done?

Comment: You haven't even told us what a cross is in your question.

Comment: This will take a lot more work, and I don't think the logic would be straightforward.

Comment: Do you roughly know the logic behind it? Because i guess the min and max x and y values of the cross wouldnt be enough

Comment: You could treat the cross as two intersecting rectangles, and then determine whether an input point falls inside either rectangle.